# not able to login to community with custom login page

Tags: apex, community

I have created a community and i have somewhat modified my community login page which on proper credentials should redirect me to community login page.

But i am not able to make my login work.I read something about site.login function and i tried to implement that but it doesn't work..i tried with simple authentication also and it also didn't help me.

It just that this is my first time on community..So hope u guys can help me here even if i m being silly.

Apex code :

```
global with sharing class CommunitiesLoginController {

    Public string userName {get;set;}
    public string passWord {get;set;}

    global CommunitiesLoginController () {


    }

    // Code we will invoke on page load.
   global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
        /*String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
        return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType); */
        return null;

       // PageReference objPageReference = new PageReference('/CommunitiesLanding');
       // return objPageReference;

    }

    public PageReference Login() {


        PageReference PageRef=Site.login(username, password, null);
        if(PageRef!=null)
        {
            system.debug('in if--->');
            PageReference PortalLogin=page.CommunitiesLanding;
            return PortalLogin;
        }else
        {
             system.debug('not in if--->');
            return null;
        }
         /* 
        if(Site.login(userName , passWord ,'') != null){
            return Site.login(userName ,passWord , '/CommunitiesLanding');
        }
        else{
           return Site.login(username, password, null);
        }

      if(username =='samir' && password == 'samir'){
            PageReference objPageReference = new PageReference('/CommunitiesLanding');
            return objPageReference ;
        }
        else {
             PageReference objPageReference = new PageReference('/CommunitiesLanding');
            return objPageReference ;
        }*/
    }

}
```

my vf page :

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" controller="CommunitiesLoginController"   title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
<apex:form >

        <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
            <apex:pageBlock >
              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Login" action="{!Login}" style="width:90px" />
               </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="UserName"></apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:inputText id="username" title="username" value="{!userName }"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Password"></apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:inputText id="Password" title="Password" value="{!passWord }"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

there is lot of commented code in controller, its because i was trying different things

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Only the following statement is correct: `if(Site.login(userName , passWord ,'') != null){
            return Site.login(userName ,passWord , '/CommunitiesLanding');
        }
        else{
           return Site.login(username, password, null);
        }` all other shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?  What results are you getting exactly?

You should be fine simply with:

```
public PageReference Login() {
  return Site.login(username, password, null);
}
```

This will forward successful login attempts to the page you define in the community setup page:

`Setup > Communities > [Community Name] > Manage > Administration > Pages > Community Home`

Unsuccessful login attempts will cause `Site.login()` to return `null`.  Therefore you can check for this and, if `null`, display an error message to the user.

For more information, see the "Customize Your Community’s Login Experience" section of the [Getting Started With Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) guide.

Comment: thank you so much Guys !!..The problem was i the cretendials i was given to login didnt had community licence.